# Web.Config Url rewrite with category

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

How to redirect http://www.domain.com/category.aspx?id=categoryname to http://www.domain.com/categoryname in web.config dynamically with change in category name.

Currently I am specifying each category separately. It is working with domain.com/category/categoryname but I want it like domain.com/categoryname

Answer (score 0):

see this blog [How to: Define Routes for Web Forms Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx)

Comment: It is working fine like this 
<rewrite url="~/Sports" to="~/Category.aspx?ID=Sports"/>
<rewrite url="~/World" to="~/Category.aspx?ID=World"/>

and also like this
<rewrite url="~/Section/(.+)" to="~/Category.aspx?ID=$1"/>

Is there a way like this where you can remove the 'Section' word and directly use like this
<rewrite url="~/(.+)" to="~/Category.aspx?ID=$1"/>
This is giving error for me